# Null values in new entities in symfony 3.4 forms without defaults

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have an entity 'administration' which has a field 'firstPeriod'. This field is not nullable (neither in the class definition nor in the database) and nor should it be, as this field should never ever be empty, the application would fail.

However, this field does not have a default value because if an oblivious user would simply submit the form without changing the default value, chaos would ensue. The user *must* make a conscious choice here. There is validation in place to ensure the field is not empty and within accepted range.

When I try to render the form, the 'propertyAccessor' of the formbuilder component throws this exception:

> Type error: Return value of AppBundle\Entity\Administration::getFirstPeriod() must be of the type integer, null returned

It looks like the formbuilder tries to get the value of the field before it is set, which ofcourse leads to said exception.

**How can I handle this situation so that the form will render without providing the user with a default value?**

To further clarify: Null is not okay, but neither is any default I can provide, the user must make a conscious decision. The same goes for any dev that instantiates this entity directly. It must be provided before the entity is persisted, but I cannot give a default because if the default is left as it is, the application will not function 12 out of 13 times.

- If I allow null on the entity field "?int" I'm effectively making a field nullable *that should never be null*
- If I provide a default, the default might be accepted blindly, which would lead to wrong results further on in the application that are very hard to spot for most users.
- I've already tried to set the 'empty_data => 0' in the formType, to no avail

*sorry for the mess below, the 'Code Sample' does not handle this code well*

My (truncated) entity:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;
```

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Administration
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="administration")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\AdministrationRepository")
 */
class Administration
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

```
/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="first_period", type="smallint", nullable=false)
 */
private $firstPeriod;

/**
 * Get id.
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}


/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getFirstPeriod(): int
{
    return $this->firstPeriod;
}

/**
 * @param int $firstPeriod
 */
public function setFirstPeriod(int $firstPeriod): void
{
    $this->firstPeriod = $firstPeriod;
}
```

}

My (truncated) formType (as best as i could get it formatted here):

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('firstPeriod', null, [
            'label' => 'First period'
        ])
    ;
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'data_class' => Administration::class
    ]);
}

public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return 'app_bundle_administration_type';
}
```

}

My controller:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller\Admin;

class AdministrationController extends Controller
{
    public function editAction(
        EntityManager $em,
        Router $router,
        Security $security,
        Session $session,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        Request $request,
        Administration $administration = null
    ): Response {

        if ($administration === null) {
            $new = true;
            $administration = new Administration();
            $pageTitle = 'New';
        } else {
            $new = false;
            $pageTitle = 'Edit';
        }
        $breadcrumbs->add($crumbs);

        $form = $this->createForm(AdministrationType::class, $administration);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            /** @var Administration $administration */
            $administration = $form->getData();

            try {
                $em->persist($administration);
                $em->flush();
            } catch (ORMException $e) {
                $logger->critical($e->getMessage());

                $session->getFlashBag()->add('error', 'Database error.');

                if ($new) {
                    return $this->redirectToRoute('administration_new');
                } else {
                    return $this->redirectToRoute(
                        'administration_edit',
                        ['administration' => $administration->getId()]
                    );
                }
            }

            $session->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Success!');

            return $this->redirectToRoute('administration_index');
        }

        return $this->render(':Admin/Administration:edit.html.twig', [
            'administrationForm' => $form->createView(),
            'pageTitle' => $pageTitle
        ]);
    }
}
```

My validation:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Administration:
properties:
    firstPeriod:
        - NotBlank:
              message: 'adm.firstperiod.empty'
        - Range:
              min: 1
              max: 13
              minMessage: 'adm.firstperiod.too_low'
              maxMessage: 'adm.firstperiod.too_high'
```

Comment: Just use default values in your entity.  private $firstPeriod = 1;  It's something you would want to do anyways.  No point in having an entity floating around with invalid data if you can help it.

Comment: @Cerad Did you read the question?

Comment: Of course I did not read it.  Much more fun to just randomly post comments.  Intentionally allowing entities to have invalid data strikes me as a really bad idea.  But if null is okay then just change the return type on getFirstPeriod to ?int.

Comment: @Cerad Null is not okay, but neither is any default I can provide, the user _must_ make a conscious decision. The same goes for any dev that instantiates this entity directly. It must be provided before the entity is persisted, but I cannot give a default because if the default is left as it is, the application will not function 12 out of 13 times. I'll edit the question to hopefully make this more clear.

Comment: You can add a [constraint directly to the form type field](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#constraints).  This will prevent the entity from getting updated unless a value is selected.  And your setFirstPeriod type hint ensures only an int can be set.  You might consider adding validation directly to the setter as well.  The nullable mapping attribute ensures that even a non-validated entity somehow gets persisted, then the database will not be changed.

Comment: @Cerad Looks like putting constraints directly on the field does not prevent the formbuilder from calling the getter, even though the value would be discarded anyway because of the constraints. Everything I've read and tried boils down to 'allow null or provide default' leaving me with little options. For now I'm gonna allow null on the getters, but not on the setters and the database, which is ugly but will at least be somewhat workable. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.

Comment: If you really want to go hard core then make yourself a data transfer object(dto) specifically for the form.  Use public properties to avoid the need for getters/setters.  Validate the dto then pass all the information needed to create your real entity into the constructor or maybe a static create method.  Remove the setters from your entity thus making it basically immutable.  That will ensure you never have an entity floating around with invalid data.  At the cost of introducing a new object.

Comment: @Cerad, I was hoping to avoid that, I wasn't kidding when I said I truncated the entity I posted here, there's _a lot_ of other properties and complexities. I thought this was something trivial where I was simply not aware of the fix, like "use the ignore_getters constraint" or something :( Maybe this problem is not as common as I thought, it is common in our field though.

Comment: Symfony forms use a property accessor.  You can plugin your own and grab the value directory from the property.  Even if it is private.  I used to do that just to avoid what I consider to be a bunch of silly getter/setters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since symfony form uses property accessor, as @Cerad says, you can add a unmapped field to the form, and get/set the field in form events, adding a specific method for get uninitialized $first_period ...

An example code may be ...

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\AdministrationRepository")
 */ 
class Administration
{ 
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()   
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $first_period;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
  
    public function getFirstPeriod(): int
    {
        return $this->first_period;
    }

    public function setFirstPeriod(int $first_period): self
    {
        $this->first_period = $first_period;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFirstPeriodOrNull(): ?int
    {
        return $this->first_period;
    }
}
```

## Form

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Administration;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
  
class AdministrationType extends AbstractType
{ 
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('first_period', null, [
                'mapped' => false,
                'required' => false,
            ])
            ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event) {
                /** @var Administration */
                $a = $event->getData();

                $event->getForm()->get('first_period')->setData($a->getFirstPeriodOrNull());
  
            })
            ->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) {
                $f = $event->getForm()->get('first_period')->getData();

                if (is_int($f)) {
                    /** @var Administration */
                    $a = $event->getData();
                    $a->setFirstPeriod($f);
                }
            });
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Administration::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

This works fine in Symfony 4.2

Comment: I fiddled around with this a little and got it to work on 3.4, but the added complexity  and 'dummy' getters make that it somewhat defeats the purpose of finding a less hackish way to do this. Like I said to Cerad I'm gonna allow null on the getters, but not on the setters and the database for now. Still a good suggestion though, and since it's the only answer and it does work, I'll accept it.

Comment: I agree that it is easier to make a getter that allows null